# Why is ostringstream not emptying?

Tags: c++, flush, ostringstream

I'm trying to convert an int to a string via an ostringstream but every time I put data into the stream, it stays in the stream. I've tried using both `.flush()` and `<<endl` but the stream never empties. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001880/stdostringstream-and-flush-member-function) suggests I don't really get streams (I don't, still working on that) and what I'm doing is hokum and unnecessary.

```
int main()
{
  long int max = 0;
  ostringstream strs;
  for(int i=10;i<100; i++){
    for(int j = i; j < 100; j++){ 
        long int product = i*j;
        strs.flush();
        strs <<product;

        string str = strs.str(); 
        cout<<str;
        int size = str.length();
    }
  }
  cout<<max;
  return 0;
}
```

currently I get an output of

```
100/100
110/100110
120/100110120
130/100110120130
etc...
```

instead of

```
100/100
110/110
120/120
130/130
etc...
```

Comment: Why *would* it be empty? The contents of a file doesn't disappear because you read it, does it? Reading from a stream just fetches the data in the stream, it doesn't remove what's in the stream.

Comment: Have you even read the documentation of ostringstream, especially its member functions, especially flush?

Comment: @PlasmaHH yup, it said `flush: Flush output stream buffer`. I thought that would solve the problem. I'm confused because the way I'm using it, its not

Comment: @Daniel: Well, flushing buffers means to make sure the data reaches its final destination, which in your case is the internal string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::ostringstream` is a writer interface to a string. Using `<<` appends to the string, and `flush` is superfluous, since the string does not have a buffer.

To change the string to which the stream writes (such as to an empty one), use the setting version of its `str()` member function:

```
strs << product;
string str = strs.str();
strs.str(""); // reset string written into
```

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way to handle this is to create a new `stringstream` object every time you want it to be empty. In most cases (including yours) this is easily handled by simply letting the existing object go out of scope, and having a new one that's created when you re-enter the correct scope.

Personally, I'd do the job by moving all the code to convert from `int` to `std::string` into a function that has a local stringstream object, so a "clean" stringstream is created every time you call the function, and destroyed when you leave it.

```
std::string to_string(long int in) { 
    std::stringstream buffer; // New/empty every time this function is called
    buffer << in;
    return buffer.str();
}                             // here buffer goes out of scope and is destroyed.

int main()
{
  long int max = 0;
  for(int i=10;i<100; i++){
    for(int j = i; j < 100; j++) {
        long int product = static_cast<long>(i)*j;
        std::string str = to_string(product);

        // presumably:
        // if (product > max) max = product;

        std::cout << str;

        // you never seem to use this:
        //int size = str.length();
    }
  }
  cout<<max;
  return 0;
}
```

A couple of notes: if your compiler is reasonably recent, it may already have an `std::to_string` in its standard library, so you can just use that instead of writing your own.

Also note the cast to `long` before multiplying `i` and `j`. Given the values you're using right now, this isn't strictly necessary, but neither is the use of `long` for `product`. Assuming you might ever use values where `product` could be larger than will fit in an `int`, the cast becomes necessary. Without it, you're doing multiplication on two `int`s, which naturally produces an `int` result. *Then* you're taking that result (which has already overflowed if it's too large to fit in an `int`) and converting it to long. By converting one of the operands to `long` before the multiplication, you force the multiplication to be carried out on `long`s as well, preventing the overflow (at least assuming `long` is large enough to hold the result).

Answer (score 0):

clear the ostringstream.buffer thus:

```
strs.str("");
```

Comment: That just resets the flags, it will not change the string buffers contents.

Answer (score 0):

To reset an `std::ostringstream`, you just assign a new buffer:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
// ...
oss.str(std::string());
```

However, most of the time that's not necessary since you can define/initialize your stringstream in the narrowest scope possible to get that automatically. In your case, you'll probably want to define it inside the outer for loop.

Comment: -1: That won't work, `str()` returns a *copy* of the underlying string.

Answer (score 0):

Put ostringstream into scope, so that it will be recreated each time you enter it. In your case it will be:

```
int main()
{
  long int max = 0;
  {
  ostringstream strs;
  for(int i=10;i<100; i++){
    for(int j = i; j < 100; j++){ 
        long int product = i*j;
        strs.flush();
        strs <<product;

        string str = strs.str(); 
        cout<<str;
        int size = str.length();
    }
  }
}

  cout<<max;
  return 0;
}
```